# Cannot open safari from table

Tags: ios, uitableview, safari

I am trying to learn how to use tables, I have my app which is a multiple view app.  I can get it to load the table with data, when I click the table item I wanted it to load another viewcontroller, this wasn't working (no errors, just nothing changed), so I decided to test it with a safari page instead and this also doesn't do anything. Any ideas?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

  //  SecondViewController *loadview = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 //   [self.navigationController pushViewController:loadview animated:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];    
   // [loadview release];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write `http://` in your URL string to open Safari with `openURL:` method.
Try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];
```

Comment: thanks, thought it would be something easy.. however I'm still struggling to get my new view to open (SecondViewController) it doesnt error and goes through the function without any issues but the screen doesnt show, it remains on the table view.